# Flight from Nigeria to Bahamas without US/UK transit

Tags: air-travel, cuba, bahamas

How can I fly to the Bahamas from Nigeria. I can't transit through any of the US states or UK. Through Cuba may be a better route, according to inquiries but how to go about it is my problem. No agent seems to know how to route the ticket.

Comment: Hello Brian, welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately questions about shopping for goods and services are off-topic here. And I'm not clear if *you* cannot travel via the UK or US, or if there is no way to get from Nigeria to the US and then from the US to the Bahamas. I find that improbable.

Comment: The question seems to be a routing problem rather than a shopping one but I understand there is a fine line between them.

Comment: Why can't you transit through US or UK? Please update your question.

Comment: @Itai It's not a price-shopping question at all. But it is a "Please find me an itinerary" question, and it should have been closed for that reason, instead.

Comment: IMO, this the issue here i finding a route given some constraints. I have myself encountered some difficult ones that stomp flight search engines.

Comment: Are you aware that visas to Bahamas are issued by British Counsel too? So you still has to contact them, if you need a visa

Answer (score 4):

This does not seem to be a difficult task.

Two quick searches say that you can go from Lagos, Nigeria to Nassau Bahamas on Royal Air Maroc followed by Air Canada with one stop in Casablanca and one stop in Montreal.

Expedia can find all the flights for you but you need to search for Lagos to Montreal and then Montreal to Nassau. Otherwise, it gives you results passing through the US since these are more direct routes. You can also book each leg of the trip the respective sites of each airline.

Should you want to use a travel agent: Do the search yourself on each site for various dates. When you find availability, note the airline, flight number and time. Then call an agent and give them all the details. They should be able to issue the tickets for you.

Comment: According the [Wiki page for the Nassau airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynden_Pindling_International_Airport), the Montreal service is seasonal (winters only.)  As far as international flights go, NAS has year-round service to Toronto Pearson, Havana, Kingston, Port of Spain, Panama City, and Port-au-Prince, so any route is probably going to have to pass through one of those points.

Comment: ITA Matrix turns up some epic routings. LOS-FRA-KEF-YYZ-NAS (8390 miles). LOS-IST-VIE-YYZ-NAS (9228 miles). LOS-LFW-GRU-YYZ-NAS (10,336 miles). By comparison, a theoretical LOS-NAS nonstop would be a mere 5450 miles. The second routing is around 12,800 USD, 7× the cost of LOS-LFW-GRU-PTY-NAS.

Comment: With Royal Air Maroc, you can go via Toronto instead from Casablanca where there is a year-round flight to Nassau, unlike from Montreal. Still, I have taken that one even at the edge of season and the weather was already quite inhospitable with a huge number of hotels and restaurant closures all over the island.

Comment: @Itai:  So far as I can tell, Royal Air Maroc doesn't fly to Toronto; it appears that their only Canadian destination is Montreal.